# Determine file extension of a dynamic image's src

Tags: javascript, image, greasemonkey

Working on a Greasemonkey script, that will take a certain action if the image loaded on a webpage is a `gif` or `jpg`. The code from the page is as follows:

```
<div id="current_photo">      
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="[url]/[random numbers].gif/jpg" alt="" style="[styles]">
    </div>
</div>
```

The start of the URL will be unique, as there is only one image on the page with that URL. Need a way to pull that path and get the extension from it.

Comment: What have you tried and how can we help you with your problem aside from entirely coding it for you?

Comment: Well, really this approach is completely new to me. The only way I know to get the extension is off a photo I know the path of. Since this image doesn't have an id or name, and I dont know what the exact path is going to be, I am actually rather stumped and dont know where to start, or how to approach it...

Answer (score 3):

The HTML in the question is malformed.  Is that really an accurate snippet?  Link to the target page.

Anyway, code like this should work:

```
var payloadImage    = document.querySelector ("#current_photo div img");

if (/\.gif$/i.test (payloadImage.src) ) {
    // DO GIF ACTION HERE
} 
else if (/\.jpg$/i.test (payloadImage.src) ) {
    // DO JPG ACTION HERE
}
else {
    // DO WHATEVER HERE
}
```

Comment: It would fail if it is `haha.gif.jpg`. (This is a valid file name for a `jpg` image.)

Comment: @Derek:  How so?  Note that the regex keys off the **last** extension -- just  like the OS.

Comment: Oh, didn't see `$` at the end... my bad.

Comment: This fails for cases where there is a URL param at the end. Such as https://www.thetimes.co.uk/imageserver/image/methode%2Ftimes%2Fprod%2Fweb%2Fbin%2F75ad7980-ecf7-11e8-8888-d940336e3709.jpg?crop=3000%2C1687%2C0%2C156&resize=2400

Answer (score 0):

Add id="something" for your image tag.  Then something like this:

```
var path = document.getElementById('something').src;
var extidx = path.lastIndexOf('.');
var extension = path.substr(extidx+1);
```

Comment: If it was my site, I would certainly do that. But I am working on a project greasemonkey script for someone else's site.